# Does R code match for what is being asked?

Tags: probability, simulation, uniform-distribution

**Question** Let U1,....,Un be i.i.d. Unif(0,1), and X = max(U1,...,Un).

(a) What is the PDF of X?

(b) What is EX?

(c) Use simulations in R (the statistical programming language) to numerically estimate EX.

**My solution**
So, the formula I got for EX is $ \frac{n}{n+1}$. I wrote an R script to estimate the value of EX, which I have shown below:

```
simfunc2 <- function(sims, n) {
  outcome <-rep(0,sims)
  for(i in 1:sims){
    x <-runif(n,0,1)
    outcome[i] <-max(x)
  }
  res <- mean(outcome)
  return(res)
}
```

so the answer for expectation I am getting using the simulation in R is 0.9903 while the answer I am getting using the mean formula is 0.9900.

Comment: What is your question?  If it's the one in the title ("does the ... code match?"), then it ought to suffice to note that nowhere does the code compute the maximum of anything, so evidently it does not simulate $X$ directly.

Comment: Besides @whuber's comment: your simulation does not 100% make sense. I am missing a "max" somewhere and a loop ;-)

Comment: I've made changes to the code. Does this match the problem statement?

Comment: Much better except for the role of `n`. According to your formula, it determines the number of uniform draws (and not the simulation size).

Comment: Yeah, that does make it confusing. I have cleaned up the code and made it less ambiguous.

Comment: Now you don't have an $n$ : )

Comment: Ok, fixed that. Everything looking good now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks perfectly fine post edits.  It's clear and well articulated, good job.

In the interests of giving you a bit more content than just a "Yup, good to go", I re-wrote your sampler in more idiomatic R

```
simulate <- function(n_sims, n_samples) {
    x <- matrix(runif(n_sims * n_samples, 0, 1), nrow = n_sims)
    maxs <- apply(x, 1, max)
    mean(maxs)
}
```

To be clear, I don't think there's anything wrong with the way you expressed the algorithm in your code, but this is what you can expect to see from experienced R programmers.

whuber comments:

> I do recommend returning the full set of simulations so they can be compared to a theoretical value, plotted, etc.

The way you would accomplish this in R is to return a list object

```
simulate <- function(n_sims, n_samples) {
    x <- matrix(runif(n_sims*n_samples, 0, 1), nrow = n_sims)
    maxs <- apply(x, 1, max)
    m <- mean(maxs)
    s <- sd(maxs)
    list(mean = m, sd = s, sims = x)
}
```

Then you can pull out the various attributes using the `$` notation

```
> sim <- simulate(1000, 2)
> sim$mean
[1] 0.6605091
> sim$sd
[1] 0.2340585
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. And thank you for showing me a better way to optimize my code. More experience in R should make me better at making cleaner code.

Comment: +1 Your code is almost identical to mine, so I can't complain.  I do recommend returning the full set of simulations so they can be compared to a theoretical value, plotted, etc.  At least return the mean and its standard error so a Z-score can be computed.  This would enable you to address the question that was implicitly asked: namely, how do we decide that a result like 0.9903 is acceptably close to 0.99?